# cannot import name 'bot_token' from 'authentication'

Tags: python

Hi so im having trouble with this python script
Here is the error

```
PS C:\Users\betha\Downloads\Ghost-chan-main> & C:/Users/betha/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe c:/Users/betha/Downloads/Ghost-chan-main/Ghost-chan-main/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\betha\Downloads\Ghost-chan-main\Ghost-chan-main\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from authentication import bot_token
ImportError: cannot import name 'bot_token' from 'authentication' (C:\Users\betha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\authentication\__init__.py)
PS C:\Users\betha\Downloads\Ghost-chan-main>
```

Here is the GitHub: https://github.com/vichannnnn/Ghost-chan
Im trying to setup this bot for my friend

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mcve], one that doesn't depend upon external links. In other words, the relevant code should be included in the question itself.

Comment: I don't see any `authentication.py` in this project. If you have own file `authentication.py` then you should create `bot_token = your_token` in this file.

Comment: I think there can be some mistake. Your code imports Python's module `authentication` which can't have `bot_token` because it wasn't create for this. You should create file `authentication.py` with `bot_token = your_token` in the same folder as you have `main.py`. Or simpler: remove `from authentication import bot_token` and put `bot_token = your_token`

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is missing file `authentication.py` with code

```
bot_token = your_token
```

Author didn't add this because there was his/her token which shouldn't be shared.

Because there was no `authentication.py` so `import` found some module with name `authentication` and it tried to get `bot_token` from this module - but this module can't have it because it wasn't created for this.

You have two solutions:

1. create file `authentication.py` with code `bot_token = your_token` in folder with project.
2. remove line

   ```
   from authentication import bot_token
   ```

   and put line

   ```
   bot_token = your_token
   ```

Comment: it says your_token is not defined. I did replace your_token with my bot token